# Cantor Set ternary representation

Tags: decimal-expansion, cantor-set

Let $I=[0,1]$ be an interval in $\mathbb{R}$

We represent all numbers in $I$ in the ternary form as $t=0_3.t_1t_2t_3...$ where $t_j=0,1$ or $2$

As per the usual construction of the Cantor set, we remove the middle third which in our case would be $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$

When we remove the middle third $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$, why does this means that we remove all numbers of the form $0_3.1t_2t_3t_4..$?

What is $0_3.1t_2t_3t_4..$?

Comment: It's $1\cdot{1\over3}+t_2\cdot{1\over 3^2}+t_3\cdot{1\over 3^3}+\cdots$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because $0_3.1t_2t_3t_4...$ is the general (ternary digital)
form of a number $\ge \frac{1}{3}$ and $\le \frac{2}{3}$

Why? Because

$0_3.1t_2t_3t_4... \ge 0.1 = \frac{1}{3}$

and in the same way

$0_3.1t_2t_3t_4... \le 0.2 = \frac{2}{3}$

In fact, to be exactly correct it should say that you do not remove
$\frac{1}{3} = 0_3.1000000...$ and $\frac{2}{3} = 0_3.1222222...$ which are the ends of this interval.
But indeed you remove all the others.